# Formatting to Export from Sheets to Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on an app/sheets combination scoring system for a tournament. The current data in the Firebase database is stored under a tag like so: **tag:**`"[\"Test\",-1,12,3]"`
The data is in the form of a list containing a single string and 3 numbers. Each index in the list will be stored in consecutive cells so referencing the data is easy. The difficulty I am having is formatting the data from the sheet to write it to the database in the same format.
Using JSON.stringify doesn't quite give me what I'm looking for:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(22,24,4,1);
var data = JSON.stringify(range.getValues());
```

result:
**tag:**`"[[\"Test1\"],[70],[0],[18]]"`

This is not quite the same as the rest of the data as I'm turning the entire range to a string by using stringify, but I don't know of a way to format the data to be stored as [string, int,int,int]. I am new to app scripts and java (hence my lack of knowledge of functions) and was hoping somebody knows of another way to write the range of cells to match the data stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, Google Apps Scripts uses JavaScript, not Java.

Second thing `getValues()` returns a Array of Arrays where each inner Array has the values of a row from the corresponding range. In order to get what you are looking for you have to flatten the result of `getValues()`. One way to do this is this:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(22,24,4,1);
var data = JSON.stringify(range.getValues().map([value] => value));
```

```js
var values = [["Test1"],[70],[0],[18]];
var data = JSON.stringify(values.map(([value]) => value));
console.info(data)
```

Comment: [.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @TheMaster I just found [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Curious thing .flat() and .flatMap() are not included in the Google Apps Script autocomplete list of methods for Array objects.